# How to execute javascript code inside an HTML page that was requested by the Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The only related question I found for my issue is this one:
[page fetched by AJAX cannot execute any javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368613/page-fetched-by-ajax-cannot-execute-any-javascript)

But I don't want do use JQuery. I want to use vanilla javascript.

The problem is that I can't execute any javacript that is inside an html page that is fetched using the fetch api.

Here are my files:

`index.html`: This is the initial HTML page. It requests a file called `index.js` as an ES6 module

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <main id="content" role="main"></main>
</body>

</html>
```

Then I have my `index.js` file:

```js
import openTemplate from './shared-assets/js/openTemplate.js';

const target = document.getElementById('content');

openTemplate('dashboard.html', target);
```

This is the `openTemplate.js` file:

```js
export default function openTemplate(templatePath, targetElement){
    fetch(templatePath).then(response => {
        response.text().then(html => targetElement.innerHTML = html);
    });
}
```

And finally, the `dashboard.html` template that refuses to execute javascript:

```html
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<script type="module">
    import myAlertFunction from 'myAlertFunction.js';

    // this is just a function that encapsulates an alert call
    // my real code will have much more complex functions being imported
    myAlertFunction('test');
</script>
```

All this code should result in a scenario in which, when my `index.html` page loads, an alert should display with the text 'test', but this is not happening.

I want this to run on Firefox Quantum >= 66

What am I missing?

Comment: Heads Up!! `'use strict';` has no meaning in a module.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Can you provide me a link to a documentation?

Comment: found it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_modules

Comment: Thanks @Keith :D

Comment: No problem, this has the relevant bits too -> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code

Comment: back to the problem,  do you get an errors in the console,. and do you get anything in the network tab?.

Comment: It does not work like that, you are trying to make available a function in the global scope. From your module watch for an event, is the regular easy way.

Comment: @Cryptopat what do you mean?

Comment: @Keith no errors in the console. The HTML is loaded, but the javascript is not executed.

Comment: Ah, right..  `innerHTML ` does not execute script tags.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: you will need to build and append a script element rather than using innerHTML